# Array Elements Empty Except First

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check the elements in an array.  If all elements except the first one are empty, then print out the array.

I am using the linq  " Are all elements Empty function ".  I'm not sure this is the correct syntax.

```
bool a = items.All(element => element == "");
```

Here is my code, it is not catching the Line 4 which is a a target line to identify of the commented lines.

```
    private void CheckForQualifyArray(string line)
    {
        // "COMBINED ACCUMULATED TOTALS","","","","","","FINAL RESULTS",
        // "Primary Election","","","","","61 Of 61 Vote Centers Reporting","",
        // "March 3, 2020","","","","","","Collin County",
        // "1","","","","","","",
        // "STATISTICS","","","","","","",
        // "","TOTAL","Election Day","Early Voting","Mail","","",

        string[] input = line.Split(',');
        int arraySize = input.Length - 1;
        string[] items = new string[arraySize];

        items[0] = input[1].ToString();
        items[1] = input[2].ToString();
        items[2] = input[3].ToString();
        items[3] = input[4].ToString();
        items[4] = input[5].ToString();
        items[5] = input[6].ToString();
        items[6] = input[7].ToString();


        // Are all elements Empty
        bool a = items.All(element => element == "");

        if (a)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(line);

        }

    }
```

Comment: How are you getting this line, is it a csv file? Is quotes here a part of string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Linq as the following

```
var input = line.Split(',').ToList();
if(input.Skip(1).All(x=>x.Equals("\"\""))) // Condition based on note below
{
     Debug.WriteLine(line);
}
```

[`Enumerable.Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8) allows you to skip/bypass the required number of elements, and returns the remaining elements. You could then use [`Enumerable.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.8) for checking the required condition.

**Note Based on Samples in OP**

Based on the samples lines given in the question, it is unclear whether you want to check if the string is `Empty` or `""` (Quotes are part of string).

In case you want to check for `String.Empty` you could modify your condition above as

```
if(input.Skip(1).All(x=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
{
     Debug.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create a new array, just use [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8) method to omit the first element from array of `line` items and then use [`All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.8). `ToString()` call is also redundant in your code, because `input` is already an array of strings

You can also use [`IsNullOrEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8) method to check that string is empty instead of comparison with empty string

```cs
string[] input = line.Split(',');

// Are all elements Empty
bool a = input.Skip(1).All(element => string.IsNullOrEmpty(element));
```

If quotes itself represent a part of string (it seems so), then `All` method predicate should care about the quotes (not the empty string)

```cs
bool a = input.Skip(1).All(element => element == @"""");
```